# Unable to install LSTM supporting libraries

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I have installed python3.6, later installed pycharm enivornment. In pycharm I went to setting -> interpretator -> Available packages, I started installing packages numpy, scipy, matplotlib, tensorflow-gpu, keras.

Later I was checking for lstm libraries, 
intially it created error that i need to install visual studio, I installed visual studio and tried to install again, it showed error no wheel packages available, so installing wheel packages I reinstalled all the above packages again.

But I cannot still install rlstm. 
It gives the error as in the picture
[image]

The complete [error log](https://file.town/download/tz8p3ob1ut6uvhbs7fub95jt6)  can be downloaded

Please suggest if I have installed correctly or if wrong what could be the right way. I want to use tensorflow for building RNN and LSTM. 
How to rectify the error.

I have no problem in importing the other libraries than LSTM.

Comment: If you install TensorFlow, you don't need other libraries to construct LSTMs. Just use functions like `tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell`. or `tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell`.

Comment: thank you , i will try and update